# windows 10 php 7.4.8 enable LDAP module is not active

Tags: ldap, php-7.4

I want to enable LDAP module on my XAMPP php 7.4.8 Windows 10.

after follow this instruction in LDAP section

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/configuration/enable-modules/#ldap

restart apache and check phpinfo, there is no section LDAP module active in phpinfo.

How to enable LDAP module in php 7.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the path\to\xampp\php directory has the following files

libeay32.dll
libsasl.dll
ssleay32.dll
Usually, you can find these files in path\to\xampp\sendmail - this library also uses them. But if not, try to search for them inside the xampp directory.

2. Uncomment or add the ldap extension in the php.ini (path\to\xampp\php\php.ini) file

extension=ldap
Restart the server

3. Make sure the path\to\xampp\php directory is set in the system environment variable PATH.

Comment: Cool, for step no 2, I think using extension: php_ldap like in php7.0 ~ 7.3, but for php7.4 use extension: ldap. LDAP module in PHP 7.4 is active now. thanks.

Comment: awesome :) , glad you are able to fix the issue